# How to set the image for imageview from library wheen we click on imageview?

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application.In that I want to set the image for imageview.So when iam click on imageview,in that time only library will be open.For that i use the below method.But library will be opened at every click at every where.

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event.
```

But i want to open the library when iam click on imageview only.Please tell me how to solve this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `myImageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES` and then use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 0):

Use TapDetecingView from Apple's official documentation. [TapDetectingView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Listings/3_Tiling_Classes_TapDetectingView_h.html)
Then create a view that subclasses TapDetectingView and contains only your image view. Finally, implement the method:

> - (void)tapDetectingView:(TapDetectingView *)view
>     gotSingleTapAtPoint:(CGPoint)tapPoint;

Answer (score 0):

i think it is not possible
better to try other options man....